# Python: Non capturing group is not working in Regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm using non-capturing group in regex i.e., `(?:.*)` but it's not working.

I can still able to see it in the result. How to ignore it/not capture in the result?

**Code:**

```
import re

text = '12:37:25.790 08/05/20 Something   P  LR    0.156462 sccm   Pt   25.341343 psig something-else'

pattern = ['(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d)\s{1}',
           '(?P<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)\s',
           '(?P<pr>(?:.*)Pt\s{3}\d*[.]?\d*\s[a-z]+)'
          ]

result = re.search(r''.join(pattern), text)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> result.group('pr')
            
'Something   P  LR    0.156462 sccm   Pt   25.341343 psig'
```

**Expected output:**

```
'Pt   25.341343 psig'
```

**More info:**

```
>>> result.groups()
            
('12:37:25.790', '08/05/20', 'Something   P  LR    0.156462 sccm   Pt   25.341343 psig')
```

Comment: Remove `(?:.*)` https://regex101.com/r/X69k0V/1 and if the digits can not be optional `(?P<pr>Pt\s{3}\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s[a-z]+)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird There is one more group before this pattern, which I want to capture. So, it's not possible to remove this.

Comment: What do you want to capture before? Like this? `.*\b(?P<pr>Pt\s{3}\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s[a-z]+)` https://regex101.com/r/sA3atN/1

Comment: Like this? `(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d)\s{1}(?P<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)\s.*?(?P<pr>Pt\s{3}\d*[.]?\d*\s[a-z]+)` https://regex101.com/r/dQULqz/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantifier is inside the named group, you have to place it outside and possibly make it non greedy to.

The updated pattern could look like:

```
(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d)\s{1}(?P<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)\s.*?(?P<pr>Pt\s{3}\d*[.]?\d*\s[a-z]+)
```

**Note** that with he current pattern, the number is optional as all the quantifiers are optional. You can omit `{1}` as well.

If the number after Pt can not be empty, you can update the pattern using `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` matching at least a single digit:

```
(?P<time>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3})\s(?P<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)\s.*?(?P<pr>Pt\s{3}\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s[a-z]+)
```

- `(?P<time>` Group *time*
- `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3}` Match a time like format
- `)\s` Close group and match a whitespace char
- `(?P<date>` Group *date*

  - `\d\d/\d\d/\d\d` Match a date like pattern
- `)\s` Close group and match a whitespace char
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline, as least as possible
- `(?P<pr>` Group *pr*

  - `Pt\s{3}` Match Pt and 3 whitespace chars
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\s[a-z]+` Match a whitespace char an 1+ times a char a-z
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4pD7qX/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the reason for adding non-capturing for decimal number i.e., `(?:\.\d+)`?

Comment: @shaikmoeed It means that you first match 1 or more digits and optionally match a dot followed by 1 or more digits. So the non capturing group makes matching a dot and the following digits as a whole optional to prevent matching `123.` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the non-capturing group from your named group. Using a non-capturing group means that no new group will be created in the match, not that that part of the string will be removed from any including group.

```
import re

text = 'Something   P  LR    0.156462 sccm   Pt   25.341343 psig something-else'

pattern = r'(?:.*)(?P<pr>Pt\s{3}\d*[.]?\d*\s[a-z]+)'

result = re.search(pattern, text)
print(result.group('pr'))
```

Output:

```
Pt   25.341343 psig
```

Note that the specific non-capturing group you used can be excluded completely, as it basically means that you want your regex to be preceded by anything, and that's what `search` will do anyway.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It works after keeping a non-capturing group before the `pr` group.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion regarding the meaning of "non-capturing" here: It does not mean that the result omits this part, but that no match group is created in the result.

Example where the same regex is executed with a capturing, and a non-capturing group:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search(r'(?P<grp>foo(.*))', 'foobar')
>>> match.groups()
('foobar', 'bar')
>>> match = re.search(r'(?P<grp>foo(?:.*))', 'foobar')
>>> match.groups()
('foobar',)
```

Note that `match.group(0)` is the same in both cases (group 0 contains the matching part of the string in full).